# How i can use Type Script class in Coffee Script?

Tags: typescript, webpack, coffeescript

i have typescript class:

```
export class StorageFactory{...}
```

And i have coffeescript file:

```
console.log StorageFactory
```

This is `undefined`

I have webpack config:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        "StorageFactory": "StorageFactory",
        "window.StorageFactory": "StorageFactory",
 })
```

and alias:

```
alias: {
   "StorageFactory":path.resolve("../factories/_b-storage-factory.js")
 }
```

How i can use this?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use the JavaScript file here:

```
alias: {
   "StorageFactory":path.resolve("../factories/_b-storage-factory.js")
}
```

Comment: It is not reason